# How to properly limit __builtins__ in eval in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, eval

In python 2.7 I could limit the `__builtins__` namespace used by eval by defining global as `{'__builtins__': None}`. This does not seem to work in Python 3.5.

Python 2.7 correctly gives the NameError:

```
In [1]: eval('round', {'__builtins__': None})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-dc1cae9c6b26> in <module>()
----> 1 eval('round', {'__builtins__': None})

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'round' is not defined
```

Python 3.5 gives the following:

```
In [1]: eval('round', {'__builtins__': None})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-83a8846287f1> in <module>()
----> 1 eval('round', {'__builtins__': None})

<string> in <module>()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Both give the correct output for the following:

```
In [1]: eval('round')
Out[1]: <function round>
```

How do I properly limit `__builtins__` or work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it to an empty dictionary:

```
eval('round', {'__builtins__': {}})
```

This will reproduce the `NameError` you got in Python 2.x.  However, sandboxing Python, whether 2 or 3, is an [inherently hard problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/191628/153279).  If possible, you should use something less powerful like [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval()`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Is there another method to evaluate math operations, e.g. '1+1'? AFIK, `ast.literal_eval` doesn't permit this.

Comment: The other components in `ast` are powerful enough to build a parser for whatever subset of the language you want... but it may be a significant amount of work, and you need to be very careful about allowing attribute access (i.e. the `foo.bar` dotted syntax).